# Getting back the exact address using building number and postcode - UWP - MapService

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

so i'm trying to retrieve the full address using the `MapLocationFinder` class in MapService for UWP.

I'm using the function `FindLocationsAsync` and I'm passing in the following:

```
MapLocationFinderResult result = await
                    MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(BuildingNumber + ", " + PostCode, null);
```

Where building number is 20 and postcode is SW11 1BP. For some reason, this isn't returning the street name... the Address variable does not contain anything apart from that it is in London. What am I doing wrong? I thought I could do a full address lookup by postcode and street number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're searching for "20, SW11 1BP" isn't a well defined query string. If you want an exact address match you'll need to supply the house number and street, the service can't work with just a house number and post code. The result you're getting is the best match given the ambiguous string - it's finding just the post code. The lat/long returned will be the center of the post code which may or may not be near the street, so a reverse geocode on that lat/long may not return the correct street and definitely won't be accurate to that building number.

Comment: if this were a fully fledged application, do you think i can get away with users having to type the name of the street in? I'm not too keen on paying for a service where i can request using the building number and postcode just to get the address...

Comment: Yes, most applications that ask users to enter an address will have fields for the most common parts of an address (house number, street, city, Admin Division such as province or state, post-code, etc.). The more fields a user can provide, the higher the confidence will be on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please check document [**Perform geocoding and reverse geocoding**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/geocoding) . We must specify a maps [authentication key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key) before you can use map services. For using map service we also need to [enable the location capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location#enable-the-location-capability).

And you could check `MapLocationFinderResult` `Status` property to make sure the query successfully.

```
MapService.ServiceToken = "Token";
MapLocationFinderResult result =
      await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(
                       BuildingNumber  + ", " + PostCode, null);

if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
{
    var Text = "result = (" +
       result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Latitude.ToString() + "," +
    result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Longitude.ToString() + result.Locations[0].DisplayName + ")";
}
```

If above address does not contain street name, you could use above Latitude Longitude to reverse Geocode then call `FindLocationsAtAsync` method to get the address.

```
MapLocationFinderResult result =
          await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(
                           BuildingNumber  + ", " + PostCode, null);
if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
{
    var temp = "result = (" +
       result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Latitude.ToString() + "," +
    result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Longitude.ToString() + result.Locations[0].DisplayName + result.Locations[0].Address.Street + ")";

    BasicGeoposition location = new BasicGeoposition();
    location.Latitude = result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Latitude;
    location.Longitude = result.Locations[0].Point.Position.Longitude;
    Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(location);

    // Reverse geocode the specified geographic location.
    MapLocationFinderResult MyResult =
          await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);

    // If the query returns results, display the name of the town
    // contained in the address of the first result.
    if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
    {
        var text = "Street = " +
              MyResult.Locations[0].Address.Street;
    }
}
```